# Flutter - tiny thin line above navigation bar for some height values?

Tags: flutter

I have an app where I'm trying to do a custom dialog UI where I darken the screen (except for the app bar). The way I'm implementing this is I'm turning both my navigation bar and body content into stacks, with a translucent black layer at the top of the stack.

My issue is that there is a tiny thin line (about the height of 1-2 pixels) where the darkened layers don't overlap.

I've tried everything - setting navigation bar elevation to 0, etc but I still can't find a fix for this, other than increasing the height of the widgets in my stack by 2 pixels (which then results in "A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.0 pixels on the bottom." error messages).

Still, this "fix" is really baffling to me, because it seems to imply that this problem only exists for some heights and not others, so it could potentially occur on other devices. Has anyone else run into something like this before?

The only other detail that could possibly be relevant is that this scaffold is displayed under a GoRouter ShellRoute.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your code, or even better, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you provide some simplified code? And Can I ask why you try to make a custom diolog ui with all those stack and not using the standart?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the official api to do just this?
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

Assuming you'll run into less hurdles...

Comment: I wanted the app bar to stay visible as the new dialog slides out from underneath it - does ShowDialog support this? As an initial naive thought, I guess in the Dialog I could try to draw a new app bar over the existing one to make it appear as if it stays in focus.

Comment: See accepetd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445392/display-snackbar-on-top-of-alertdialog-widget
(not most voted answer, the one with a green V)