# How can I raise snackBar to the top?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a menu in showModalBottomSheet.

If I click a ListTile in the menu, a snackBar and a message appear in the screen, but showModalBottomsheet is above snackBar.

So snackBar is hidden behind showModalBottomSheet. How can I raise snackBar to the top? or could you give me some advice?

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445392/display-snackbar-on-top-of-alertdialog-widget

Answer (score 0):

Use a new Scaffold(ScaffoldMessenger) for the Snackbar, this will avoid the showModalBottomSheet to hide the Snackbar.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    const SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        "Snackbar text goes here"));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  },
  child: Text("menu item"),
)
```