Flutter snackbar on top of ModalBottomSheet issue
I'm trying to display snackbars on top of ModalBottomSheet but didn't find any way to make it work. (searched all topics here)
Mainly the ModalBottomSheet is launched by pressing a button on a screen and opens another screen inside of it. The snackbar is shown behind this bottomsheet, so it seems that the context given as an argument coresponds to the initial screen.
How I call the bottomsheet:
press: () {
          customModalBottomSheet(
            context,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.92,
            child: XScreen(),
          );
        },

In XScreen I use the following snackbar to show messages:
 final snackBar = SnackBar(
        elevation: 0,
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        content: AwesomeSnackbarContent(
          title: 'Error!',
          message:
          'Error message',
          contentType: ContentType.failure,
        ),
      );

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(snackBar);

Thank you!

you can wrap bottomSheet content with a Scaffold,

@Md.YeasinSheikh you mean the child right? Doesn't work

Can you share a sample snippet that will reproduce your issue

Is there any specific changes on customModalBottomSheet

@Md.YeasinSheikh clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
isScrollControlled: true,
isDismissible: isDismissible,
enableDrag: isDismissible and builder: (context) => SizedBox(
height: height ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
child: child,
),

You can follow this snippet, it will show the snackbar inside BottomSheet.
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (builder) => Scaffold(//i wonder if there any better way of doing this
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.maybeOf(context)
                ?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Heia")));
          },
          child: Text("Show snackbar"),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);


there is one issue, let me see if I can fix the duplicates

Still shows behind :(

Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68446126/10157127

managed to find a solution. ScaffoldMessenger and Scaffold together did the trick. Thank you
